# Proof on Greeks for a delta neutral portfolio

Tags: finance

Suppose that $ \Delta S $ is the price change of an underlying asset during a small time interval $\Delta t$ and $ \Delta \pi$ is the corresponding price change in the portfolio. Show that $ \Delta \pi = \Theta \Delta t + \frac{1}{2} \Gamma \Delta S^2$ for a delta neutral portfolio, where $\Theta$  is the theta of the portfolio, and where terms of higher order that $\Delta t$ are ignored.

---

For a delta nuutral portfolio, it is required that

$\frac{\Delta \pi }{\Delta S} =0 $

For theta :

$\Theta = \frac{\Delta \pi}{\Delta t}$

For Gamma :

$\Gamma = \frac{\Delta \pi ^2}{\Delta ^2 S}$

I am confused whether to write $\Delta$ or use $\partial$ instead. And I don't know how to get the equation required.

Comment: I'm seeing a bunch of boxes ▯ and question mark diamonds � in your question. Can you edit it to be readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the portfolio be $\pi=\pi(S,t)$. So we have the Taylor expansion
$$
\Delta\pi\approx\underbrace{\frac{\partial\pi}{\partial S}}_{\text{Delta}\,\Delta_\pi}\times\Delta S+\underbrace{\frac{\partial\pi}{\partial t}}_{\text{Theta}\,\Theta_\pi}\times\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\frac{\partial^2\pi}{\partial S^2}}_{\text{Gamma}\,\Gamma_\pi}\times(\Delta S)^2+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2\pi}{\partial t^2}\times(\Delta t)^2+\cdots}_{\text{ignored}}
$$
and for a delta neutral portfolio $\Delta_\pi=0$, ignoring terms of higher order that $\Delta t$,  we have
$$\boxed{
\Delta\pi\approx\Theta_\pi\times\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}\Gamma_\pi\times(\Delta S)^2}
$$